# lost stash and commit

Tags: git, github

I commit and stashed some work and now when changing back to the branch and trying to apply the stash I seem to be behind (about two weeks worth of work).

Here is what I did via terminal history:

```
$ git checkout dashboard-improvements
$ git pull
$ git stash apply "stash@{0}" (all is well at this point)
$ git status (finished working, wanted to see my changes)
$ git stash (received a warning about files not being commit)
$ git add -A && git commit -m "" (received a warning about blank commit message)
$ git add -A && git commit -m "create order" "
"
$ git stash
$ git checkout staging && git pull
```

At this point I continued to work on some other branches and projects.

I then went back to the dashboard-improvements branch and tried to apply my latest stash, but I am seeing old work:

```
$ git branch (viewed my branches)
$ git checkout dashboard-improvements
$ git status
$ git stash apply "stash@{0}" (seeing really old work)
```

I'm kind of panicking and I'm not really sure what to do.  I've tried `$git fsck --lost-found` and there are a ton of dangling commits, but I'm afraid to play around and potentially lose my work.

Is there a way to see the local commit with the sketchy quotations:

```
    $ git add -A && git commit -m "create order" "
    "
```

Comment: What warning did you receive? Does `git log --graph --decorate` help?

Comment: My guess is that the stash didn't work.  But, I don't understand why you were trying to `git stash` at that point anyway.  Typically, you would only apply a stash when your working directory and stash are both clean.  So...what were you trying to stash there, and why?

Comment: What happens if the stash doesn't work?  Have I lost my work?  What about the local commit?

Comment: @Schwern that doesn't really tell me anything.  The warning would have been that I cannot stash until I commit.  Then the second warning would have been something about a blank commit

Comment: @j_quelly The more information you can give us the better.

Answer (score 1):

Let's pull apart what happened.

```
$ git checkout dashboard-improvements
$ git pull
```

Updated `dashboard-improvements` from the remote.

```
$ git stash apply "stash@{0}" (all is well at this point)
```

Applied some work from the last thing you stashed.

```
$ git status (finished working, wanted to see my changes)
```

Checked your status.

```
$ git stash (received a warning about files not being commit)
```

Stashed the changes you just applied. Why?

```
$ git add -A && git commit -m ""
```

Committed nothing, you just stashed all your changes.

```
$ git stash
```

Stashed nothing. Why?

```
$ git branch (viewed my branches)
$ git checkout dashboard-improvements
$ git status
$ git stash apply "stash@{0}" (seeing really old work)
```

At this point I have no idea what's in your stash.

---

The issue I see is you seem to be stashing as a cargo-cult thing. Your stash is probably full of all sorts of junk. Run a `git stash list -p`, look through what's there, and sort out what's useful and what isn't.

You might want to review the [Stashing and Cleaning](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) chapter of the Git Book.

Comment: As far as I know at this point ```$ git stash (received a warning about files not being commit)``` the stash did not work because there were new files created that were not commit? At least that's what I think happened. Also, this commit did not work ```$ git add -A && git commit -m ""``` because of the blank message.  It was the following commit with the extra quotations that seemed to work.  However, I cannot see in my local commit logs. I gather that stashing was unnecessary considering I just commit all of my changes. When I git log I don't see my commit ```"create order" ""```

Comment: @j_quelly I'm sorry, I don't know what warning `git stash` might have given you. Please show us the exact warnings, if you still have them. You won't see a commit for `create order` because *you had just stashed your changes* and there would be nothing to commit. `git add -A` will not add new files.

Comment: @j_quelly "the stash did not work because there were new files created that were not commit?" No. This makes no sense. The very point of stashing is to act on the working tree's pending changes. And, like Schwern, I'm baffled as to why you would stash at your 5th history line (stashing back after applying).